# Why is then() chained methods not running sequentially?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

We are trying to execute a number of AJAX calls in a particular order. The following code has **methodA, methodB** and **methodC** (each returns an AJAX promise object running *async=true*).

They are chained using the **then()** function in **jQuery**.

```
 self.methodA().then( self.methodB() ).then( self.methodC() )
```

I have made one of the methods slow (**methodB**) (I use a slow URL).

I would expect **A**... 10 second wait...then **B** then **C**.

Instead I get **A, C** ....10 second wait and **B**.

Why is it doing that? Does it have something to do with me using the alert() in an always() function?

Here is my code in a fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/h8tfrvy4/13/

Code:

```
function Tester() {
    var self = this;
    this.url = 'https://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/library/';
    this.slowurl = 'http://fake-response.appspot.com/?sleep=5';


    this.save = function() {
        self.methodA().then( self.methodB() ).then( self.methodC() )
    }

    this.methodA = function () {
        var self = this;

        return $.ajax({
            url: self.url,
            async: true
        }).always(function (processedDataOrXHRWrapper, textStatus, xhrWrapperOrErrorThrown) {

            //check for errors... and if OK
            alert('A OK');


        })
    }
    this.methodB = function () {
        var self = this;

        return $.ajax({
            url: self.slowurl,
            async: true
        }).always(function (processedDataOrXHRWrapper, textStatus, xhrWrapperOrErrorThrown) {

            //check for errors... and if OK
            alert('B OK');


        })
    }
    this.methodC = function () {
        var self = this;

        return $.ajax({
            url: self.url,
            async: true
        }).always(function (processedDataOrXHRWrapper, textStatus, xhrWrapperOrErrorThrown) {
            //OK
            alert('C OK');

        })
    }
}
new Tester().save();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
self.methodA().then( self.methodB() ).then( self.methodC() )
```

You're invoking each method **immediately**, and passing the promises into `then`.

If you want each function to wait until the previous finishes, you need to give each `then` a callback to execute when the previous promise resolves:

```
self.methodA().then(function () { return self.methodB() }).then(function() { return self.methodC() });
```

Comment: No need to make empty functions when you can just ommit the parantheses: `self.methodA().then(self.methodB).then(self.methodC)`

Comment: @L3viathan Yes, there is. Your way is broken, `methodB` and `methodC` would not have the correct `this`.

Comment: excuse my naive thinking : But wouldn't the 'non-wrapped' version I have also pass a promise to the then() ? Or the promise is being passed as a paramter into then(). But yes, your version works.

Comment: @OliverWatkins Yes, it passes a promise to `then`, but that's **not** what `then` is for. `then` expects a callback which itself *may* return a promise. That's the whole point of using `then`. Otherwise you're invoking all three methods, A, B and C, at the same time, and they will resolve in whatever order they happen to resolve in, mostly dependent on how long each request takes. If that's your goal, then you don't need `then` at all, you want `when`. But if you want the requests to start and finish in order, you need the `then(function () { ... })` line that I've provided.

Comment: @Oliver Watkins Actually, you already have functions returning promises, they're called methodB and methodC. So we can just use those functions directly as the thing .then() calls. That is the shorter and simpler solution because it doesn't add an extra unnecessary set of function wrappers to the mix. See my corrected answer for the simplest solution.

Comment: @JohnMunsch Yes, it's shorter code, but it's **not** equivalent.  The function wrappers are **not unnecessary**, they are required to maintain the value for `this` inside the callbacks. Your answer is still wrong, this was already covered in the comments before yours, and rejected for the same reasons.

Answer (score 3):

Short and simple:

```
this.save = function() {
    self.methodA().then( self.methodB ).then( self.methodC )
}
```

It has bothered me all **&^*$& day that @meagar was right and I was wrong on this one but I was sure that I was right. His answer seemed too complicated and but I was fuzzy headed in the morning and my answer wasn't right either. This *is* the right answer and it works perfectly when you plug it into the JSFiddle.

Comment: putting the 'returns' in there gives me Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token return

Comment: How was this upvoted 4 times? It's **completely wrong.** It's not even syntactically correct. @OliverWatkins The community has not done a good job sorting answers for you in this case.

Comment: Your new answer is still wrong. Look at the implementation of `methodB` and `methodC`.  The very first lines are `var self = this`, and the methods are dependent on certain properties being present on `this`. Your new code decouples `methodB` and `methodC` from "self", and **cannot work** given their implementation. `this` will be either `window` or `null` in strict mode, so your code will fail.

Comment: @meagar Yes, you're absolutely right. You should really delete *three additional lines* to get to a still simpler version. Since self is defined in the outer scope, it's visible to methods A, B, and C. So by deleting the var self = this from each one, there's no scope confusion. Here it is in a a single fiddle that works great: https://jsfiddle.net/JohnMunsch/fbujjk8q/ Note: I swapped out http://fake-response.appspot.com/?sleep=5 for http://httpbin.org/delay/5 because appspot doesn't handle CORS so we were getting an error on the B call.